# Any way to stop VMwareUser process from crashing and consuming 99% of CPU?

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-server, vmware-workstation

I'm running Windows Server 2008 x32 under VMware Workstation v6.5.2.

VMwareUser.exe process crashes regularly, and uses 95% of CPU until its shut down manually.

When I shut down VMwareUser, I suddenly lose the ability to copy/paste between the host and guest OS's (I can't live without this so I reboot).

Any idea on how to prevent VMwareUser.exe crashing?

Comment: Does the event log have any specifics when this crash occurs? Does the vmware.log get updated with information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen similar VMWare crashes where the access to files was compromised. Either a corrupt VMDK or snapshot or insufficient free space.

Do a "CHKDSK X: /R /F /X /V" on the host file system (replace the X: with the correct drive ID) and see if it fixes things (you may have to reboot).

If that fails, try creation a new virtual disk and image the old one on to it (from within the VM). Then configure it to boot from the new disk. If your problem went away, it was probably a corrupt VMDK.

Of course if your problem is drive space, then ignore the previous and get a larger drive.

Comment: Traced it to a bad SSD (Solid State Drive). Replace it, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Lowering the priority of the VMWare process will reduce the impact it has on the host OS, but that does not addess the underlying issue.